# params break sub-module routing in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

In my angular2 app, I have two submodules (login) and (line), routing to login works fine, however, I want to route to my line module with route params, e.g. `/line/param1/param2`, but doing that break navigation...

I have the following root module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LoginModule,
    LineModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [appRoutingProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

where this is my `app.routes.ts` file:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'login/login.module', pathMatch: 'prefix'},
  { path: 'line', loadChildren:'line/line.module', pathMatch: 'prefix'}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Now my LoginModule works fine, with its child routes. However, I am facing issues with my `LineModule`.

`line.module.ts`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { LineComponent } from './line.component';
import { lineRouting } from './line.routes';
import { DataService } from './services/data/data.service';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    lineRouting
  ],
  providers:[DataService],
  declarations: [LineComponent]
})
export class LineModule { }
```

`line.routes.ts`:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LineComponent } from './line.component';

const lineRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'line',
    component: LineComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '/:dep/:id', component: LineComponent }
    ]
}];

export const lineRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(lineRoutes);
```

Now routing to `http://localhost:4200/line` works fine (I do get an error from my service, as dep and id are undefined, but the component renders). However, if I try `http://localhost:4200/line/finance/line3` then I get:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'line/line.module'.
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'line/line.module'

I get those sorts of errors if the route isn't defined correctly. I tried changing `app.routes.ts` so the path was `line/:dep/:id` but I got the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't the url be: http://localhost:4200/line/finance/line/3 ?

Comment: @Anthony I don't think so, param1(dep) is `finance`, param2(id) is `line3`

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by removing the first slash in your path, like this:

```
children: [
    { path: ':dep/:id', component: LineComponent }
]
```